# EMC surge protection

Tags: power-supply, circuit-protection, surge-protection

I have a product being EMC tested. It passed all but the surge test per IEC 61000-4-5. For mitigation, they have suggested the addition of some type of surge protection circuitry like MOVs.

The specifics of the surge test are: 1.2 μs × 50 μs is the surge pulse. The surges are +/-500 V, +/-1000 V and +/-2000 V. Each voltage level and polarity is discharged 5 times each and at 0°, 90°, 180°, and 270° of the AC waveform. Each discharge is 1 minute apart. These surges are applied to L1-GND and N-GND. The product failed at a 2000 V surge pulse.

The problem is that if I add MOVs to L-N, L-PE, and N-PE and pass the EMC test, the product will fail the hi-pot test in the Safety portion of the certification after the EMC portion is complete.

I was wondering if I could use MOVs plus GDT to pass the surge test, also, the GDT should provide the isolation I need for the hi-pot test (please see the image). Am I correct? Also, please pardon my ignorance as I am a ME, not an EE.

[image]

Comment: Without trying to sound flippant ----  Sometimes it's easier to find a different test lab that'll pass it.  Not all labs are created equal.   It's call "lab shopping" and it's more common than you might think.

Comment: So, what failed and how did it fail? Where was the circuit vulnerability i.e. what part of the circuit became the victim? In other words, the cure is best applied where the victim is rather than just slapping big MOVs across the AC rails and hoping for the best.

Comment: _”MOVs to L-N, L-PE, and N-PE”_ Yea, that won’t be legal. Clamp harder on L-N and in the DC bus?

Comment: Andy, well the unit has a linear power supply, the only thing that failed was a bridge rectifier, and the AC wires going to the rectifier had signs of overheating at a few spots. Once replaced the rectifier the unit functioned without a problem.

Comment: Are MOVs usually connected to ground?

Comment: No, MOVs are usually connected between L - N. But there are references to MOVs connection between L - PE, and N - PE, this is called common mode surge suppression.